# How to use Bootstrap CSS only in Identity area (Asp Net Core 6)?

Tags: css, layout, asp.net-core-6.0

My MVC project (Net Core 6) working without Bootstrap and if I add Bootstrap style than all my HTML-markup will be destroyed. Now I use one Layout for all areas.

[image: Layout]

But without Bootstrap Identity area looking worst and I don's want manually add each div style.

[image: Identity Area without Bootsrap]

Maybe one solution is inject URL manager (but what is the best for Asp.Net Core 6? and what service I need to add?) and create adaptive Layout - if Area is "Identity" need to load Bootstrap to header, otherwise working without it.

Or maybe this is not a best solution? Maybe there are embedded ASP.NET Core future to realize this function?

Comment: So, this is my solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73452057/bootstrap-css-how-to-remove-gap-between-h1-and-div-inside-row-defaultui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this is my solution

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1920, initial-scale=1.0" />
@if (@Context.HttpContext?.GetRouteValue("area")?.ToString() == "Identity")
{
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/canvasJS/jquery-ui.1.12.1.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/font/Gilroy/stylesheet.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined|Material+Icons+Two+Tone|Material+Icons+Round|Material+Icons+Sharp">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/style/swiper-bundle.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/style/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
}
else
{
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/canvasJS/jquery-ui.1.12.1.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/font/Gilroy/stylesheet.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined|Material+Icons+Two+Tone|Material+Icons+Round|Material+Icons+Sharp">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/style/swiper-bundle.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/style/style.css">
}
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    @await Html.PartialAsync("Header.cshtml")
    @if (@Context.HttpContext?.GetRouteValue("area")?.ToString() == "Identity")
    {
        <div id="identity" class="row">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
    }
    else
    {
        <main>
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    }
</div>
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
<script src="~/canvasJS/canvasjs.stock.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/canvasJS/jquery-ui.1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/scripts/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/scripts/script.js"></script>
@await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new Layout which contains bootstrap css,and named it with _IdentityLayout.cshml.For example:

[image]

And then change the _ViewStart.cshtml in Areas/Identity/Pages:

```
@{
    Layout = "/Views/Shared/_IdentityLayout.cshml";
}
```

Comment: This solution destroy left menu of my site, If I use Bootstrap in page https://localhost:7168/Identity/Account/Login - left menu of my site, my fonts, background and other my site styles will be full disappear. I need Bootstrap ONLY for internal part of page /Identity/Account/Login, but external wrapper of this page need to work with my style without Bootstrap.