# Bootstrap css. How to remove gap between H1 and DIV inside ROW (DefaultUI)

Tags: html, css, asp.net-identity

I have huge gap between title and div with data in Default Identity UI, I can not change HTML tags, only CSS.

[image: huge gap]

DefaultUI rendering inside @RenderBody() (inside DIV-ID="Identity") and use Bootstrap 5.0

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1920, initial-scale=1.0" />
@if (@Context.HttpContext?.GetRouteValue("area")?.ToString() == "Identity")
{
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/canvasJS/jquery-ui.1.12.1.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/font/Gilroy/stylesheet.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined|Material+Icons+Two+Tone|Material+Icons+Round|Material+Icons+Sharp">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/style/swiper-bundle.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/style/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
}
else
{
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/canvasJS/jquery-ui.1.12.1.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/font/Gilroy/stylesheet.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined|Material+Icons+Two+Tone|Material+Icons+Round|Material+Icons+Sharp">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/style/swiper-bundle.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/style/style.css">
}
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    @await Html.PartialAsync("Header.cshtml")
    @if (@Context.HttpContext?.GetRouteValue("area")?.ToString() == "Identity")
    {
        <div id="identity" class="row">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
    }
    else
    {
        <main>
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    }

</div>

<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
<script src="~/canvasJS/canvasjs.stock.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/canvasJS/jquery-ui.1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/scripts/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/scripts/script.js"></script>
@await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

This is calculated style of H1

```
border-bottom-left-radius: 18px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 18px;
border-top-left-radius: 18px;
border-top-right-radius: 18px;
box-sizing: border-box;
flex-shrink: 0;
font-family: "Gilroy";
font-size: 24px;
font-weight: 500;
letter-spacing: 1.26px;
line-height: 28.8px;
margin-bottom: 8px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
max-width: 100%;
opacity: 0.9;
outline-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
outline-style: none;
outline-width: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 12px;
padding-right: 12px;
padding-top: 0px;
text-align: center;
width: 1040px
```

This is calculated style of next DIV

```
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
border-bottom-left-radius: 18px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 18px;
border-top-left-radius: 18px;
border-top-right-radius: 18px;
box-sizing: border-box;
color: rgb(33, 37, 41);
flex-shrink: 0;
font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", "Liberation Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI     Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: 400;
letter-spacing: 1.26px;
line-height: 24px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
max-width: 100%;
outline-color: rgb(33, 37, 41);
outline-style: none;
outline-width: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 12px;
padding-right: 12px;
padding-top: 0px;
text-align: start;
width: 1040px
```

This is source style of DIV and ROW

```
#identity div {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: var(--bs-body-font-family);
    font-size: var(--bs-body-font-size);
    font-weight: var(--bs-body-font-weight);
    line-height: var(--bs-body-line-height);
    color: var(--bs-body-color);
    text-align: var(--bs-body-text-align);
    background-color: var(--bs-body-bg);
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent
}
.row {
   --bs-gutter-x: 1.5rem;
   --bs-gutter-y: 0;
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   /*margin-top: calc(var(--bs-gutter-y) * -1);*/
   margin-right: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x) * -.5);
   margin-left: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x) * -.5);
   /*margin-top: -400px;*/
   border-radius: 18px;
}
.row > * {
    flex-shrink: 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding-right: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x) * .5);
    padding-left: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x) * .5);
    /*margin-top: var(--bs-gutter-y);*/
    /* margin-top: -400px;*/
    border-radius: 18px;
}
.h1,.h2,.h3,.h4,.h5,.h6,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: .5rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 1.2 ;
    text-align: center;
}
.h1,h1 {
    font-size: calc(1.375rem + 1.5vw);
    text-align: center;
}
@media (min-width:1200px) {
    .h1,    h1 {
        font-size: 1.5rem;
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

All looking good, but I expect H1 height 100-150 px instead more than 300+ px.
What going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can remove this gap only when I restricted height of DIV, any other manipulation don't give me result, so

```
        <div id="identity" class="row" style="height:500px">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting max-height as opposed to height. It looks like it's in a flex container and might just be growing to fill the allocated space.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try changing the following properties

```
padding of heading
line-height of heading
```